# How to merge data from 2+ OData services in an sap.m.Table?

Tags: javascript, web, odata, sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 table (sap.m.Table). The items are from the OData v 4 model - they are obtained automatically (`/catalog/cars`). Each row has a `CarID` key. There is another OData v 4 service that I can call to get the count of passengers in each car:

```
/catalog/CarPassengers?$apply=groupby((CarID),aggregate($count as Items))
```

This call returns count of passengers per car.

How can I show the corresponding counts per car in the above table ?

I can make an Ajax request to the second service to get the counts, capture the response in an array of objects, save this array of object in a JSON model, make this JSON model available in a Formatter and call the formatter to look up the count based on the `CarID`, and display it in the `<m:Text />` element. The challenge with that approach is that I'll have to ensure to call this service before the table is populated.

What is the right way of doing it ?

Comment: Why not merge both sets of data into a Json Object and bind the table to this Json object using the Json Model?

Comment: why would you do this in the first place? Both entities should be in the same service - connected by a navigation attribute.

databinding in the table is a simple {= {Passengers}.length } or {= {CarPassengers /CarPassengersCount}}

Your model description is very unclear